# What is the jQuery $(this) referring to in this specific code fragment?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".po").click(function(){
                var po = $(this).text();
                var dataString = 'po='+ po;

                $.ajax
                    ({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "projectitems.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html)
                        {


$(this).closest(".resultsItems").html(html);
                        }
                    });
            });         
        });
```

The line `$(this).closest(".resultsItems").html(html);` what exactly is (this) referring to? I'm trying to append the returned ajax result to a `<td>` called .resultsItems but only to the one below the intial clicked selector? Is this possible?

Just to make it clear i'm not asking what (this) means in jQuery, i'm asking what (this) is referring to in my code above!

Comment: not really a duplicate as i'm asking what my (this) is referring to in my code

Comment: Quick tip: If you need to refer to a specific `"this"` in that block of code, you can add something like this in the appropriate context:  `var t = this;`  Further down in your function calls, you can use `$(t)` instead of `$(this)`.

Comment: @meder - this isn't a duplicate, look at my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`this` refers to the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) settings object.  To get what you want, you'll need to maintain `this` by using the `context` option like this:

```
$.ajax({
  context: this,
  type: "GET",
  url: "projectitems.php",
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  success: function(html) {
    $(this).closest(".resultsItems").html(html);
  }
});
```

Comment: Bah, that damned orange bar just as I'm wrapping up my answer.

Comment: Thanks! This is NOT a duplicate to all those people who "scanned" my question rather than reading it properly

Answer (score 3):

From the jQuery site:

> The `this` object for all of them will
>   be the object in the `context` property
>   passed to `$.ajax` in the settings; if
>   that was not specified it will be a
>   reference to the Ajax settings
>   themselves.

Comment: I looked for this (pun intended) on the jQuery site.  Where is this quote located?

Comment: @Hogan: it's here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ - the Callback Functions paragraph.

Comment: @Hogan Google for part of the phrase as a quoted string, and you will land at [the jQuery.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at that page, but I failed to scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

You can read in detail about the `this` keyword [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)

Basically, in your case it refers to the window object because it is the window object that has triggered the `success` event on your ajax call.
You can however capture the scope of the `$(".po")` just above the ajax call by doing:

```
var that = this;
```

Then if you use `that.closest()...` that will refer to the `$(".po")` object